# 403 Forbidden error when trying to refresh PowerBi dataset

Tags: powerbi

We are trying to refresh a PowerBI dataset from a background service that runs without a signed-in user.

We have registered a PowerBI App in the Azure portal and assign it all the avaliable permissions includig the Dataset.ReadWrite.All and Tenant.ReadWrite.All Application permission.
From the PowerBI portal we also registered the app as the Service Principal for the workspace and enabled all the Admin API settings in the admin page.

We are using the Microsoft Authentication lib for .NET (MSAL.NET) to generate an access token and the Microsoft.PowerBI.Api lib to interact with the PowerBI REST API.

The following C# code is throwing a 403 Forbidden error:

```
            IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create(clientId)
                .WithClientSecret(secret)
                .WithTenantId(tenantId)
                .WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, tenantId)
                .Build();

            string[] scope = { "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default" };
            AuthenticationResult authResult = await confidentialClientApplication.AcquireTokenForClient(scope).ExecuteAsync();

            TokenCredentials tokenCredentials = new(authResult.AccessToken, "Bearer");           
            PowerBIClient pbClient = new(tokenCredentials);
            
            await pbClient.Datasets.RefreshDatasetAsync(datasetId); // throw 403 - Forbidden
```

What are we missing?